# How can I rewrite generic function in C# into OOP to avoid switching on types?

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I have a client that sends requests to a server. The requests and responses are also game events so I can send the requests and responses to wherever they are needed in the code:

```
public class Message {}

public interface IOnlineRequest : IGameEvent {}

public interface IOnlineResponse : IGameEvent {}

public abstract class OnlineRequest<T> : Message, IOnlineRequest {
    public abstract T Request { get; set; }
}

public abstract class OnlineResponse<T> : Message, IOnlineResponse {
    public abstract T Response { get; set; }
}

public sealed class OPingRequest : OnlineRequest<PingRequest>
{
    public override PingRequest Request { get; set; }
}

public sealed class OPingResponse : OnlineResponse<PingResponse>
{
    public override PingResponse Response { get; set; }
}
```

There is a manager class that has the following members:

```
private SortedDictionary<int, IOnlineRequest> requests_ = new SortedDictionary<int, IOnlineRequest>();
private SortedDictionary<int, IOnlineResponse> responses_ = new SortedDictionary<int, IOnlineResponse>();
```

I iterate on requests and switch on the type (this is the part I don't like and would like to rewrite it with OOP):

```
bool error = false;
foreach (var request in requests_)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        switch (request.Value)
        {
            case OPingRequest req:
                error = await ProcessRequest<PingRequest, PingResponse, OPingResponse>(request.Key, req, Profile.PingAsync);
                break;
            case OKeepAliveRequest req:
                error = await ProcessRequest<KeepAliveRequest, KeepAliveResponse, OKeepAliveResponse>(request.Key, req, Profile.KeepAliveAsync);
                break;
            case OLoginRequest req:
                error = await ProcessRequest<LoginRequest, LoginResponse, OLoginResponse>(request.Key, req, Profile.LoginAsync);
                break;
            case OCounterRequest req:
                error = await ProcessRequest<CounterRequest, CounterResponse, OCounterResponse>(request.Key, req, Profile.CounterAsync);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Add code for your request type above!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;  // Break out of foreach
    }
}
```

And this is the generic ProcessRequest function:

```
private async Task<bool> ProcessRequest<T, U, V>(int num, OnlineRequest<T> req, Func<T, CancellationToken, Task<U>> func)
    where T : class, IMessage<T>
    where U : class, IMessage<U>
    where V : OnlineResponse<U>, new()
{
    req.State = new RequestState();
    U resp = null;

    try
    {
        resp = await func(req.Request);

        req.State.Status = RequestStatus.Success;
        req.State.Message = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        req.State.Status = RequestStatus.Failed;
        req.State.Message = ex.ToString();
    }

    responses_.Add(num, new V { State = req.State, Response = resp });

    return true;
}
```

Find it hard to re-implement this in OOP mostly because the types like `PingRequest, PingResponse` are concrete types and they are generated so I have no choice and can't change them.

What I would like to achieve is:

```
bool error = false;
foreach (var request in requests_)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        error = request.Process();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How many switch cases in your original implementation? If it's only one, it could be ok. If there is many, make a strategy pattern and a `Dictionary<type,Func>` to replace switch cases.

Comment: @LouisGo I estimate there will be 100+ request types

Answer (score 0):

> mostly because the types like PingRequest, PingResponse are concrete types and they are generated so I have no choice and can't change them

Most code generator tools have the common decency to declare types via `partial class`. That means that you can create a *separate* code file to add things **without editing the generated files**, for example an interface implementation:

```cs
namespace TheSameNamespaceAsBefore {
    partial class PingRequest : IMyInterface {
        bool IMyInterface.DoTheThing() { /* your code here */ }
    }
    partial class PingResponse : IMyInterface {
        bool IMyInterface.DoTheThing() { /* your code here */ }
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do something like:

```cs
if (request.Value is IMyInterface foo) { error = foo.DoTheThing(); }
else { /* warn? throw? set error to true? break? */ }
```

You might also be able to use a common base type, but an interface seems fine here.

(sometimes the code generator also genetes "partial methods" - stubs that you can optionally implement in your own partial class file, to provide functionality invoked at specific points in the generated code; if you don't implement them, the calls simply evaporate during compilation, as though they never existed)

Comment: Unfortunately the PingRequest is decalred like this `public sealed class PingRequest : IMessage<PingRequest>, IMessage, IEquatable<PingRequest>, IDeepCloneable<PingRequest>`

Comment: @CrHasher that's vexing; what tool is generating that? frankly, I'd log a bug with them: it is common practice to always declare generated types as `partial`

Comment: The library I use is Google Protobuf, but the issue is not on Google side because protoc is generating the class with `public sealed partial class PingRequest : pb::IMessage<PingRequest>`, but Unity is importing it from a dll as `public sealed class PingRequest : IMessage<PingRequest>, IMessage, IEquatable<PingRequest>, IDeepCloneable<PingRequest>`

Comment: @CrHasher right; you need to put your interface etc *in the dll that you are importing*; `partial` is used at compile time - once you've compiled that type: that's it. So: just put this code *over there*, in whatever dll you're generating